# error returned in function to find lognormal for calculation

Tags: r

Finding Lnorm of a function

I imported the lognorm import.(lognorm). When I tried to run the code below, I got the error

```r
L <- lrnorm(10, 1)
```

> Error in lrnorm(10, 1) : could not find function "lnorm"

Comment: Please be careful when posting code samples. You have `lrnorm` in your example code, and then `lnorm` in the error message, it makes it hard to understand what's happening. If you're using a library show the `library(name)` call in your example code as well.

Comment: @Marius. Thanks for pointing, I'll change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably meant `rlnorm(10, 1)`:

```
rlnorm(10, 1)

[1] 2.9912069 1.9946569 1.7922328 7.9434553 5.7672878 1.0603424 3.2814964
[8] 0.4145954 0.7273603 3.7008232
```

But, `rlnorm` is just a base R function, and not part of the `lognorm` package.